# C# generics and type checking confusion

Tags: c#, generics, types

To start, some classes:

```
public abstract class Component
{
    GenericSystem mySystem;

    public Component() { mySystem = null;}

    public void SetSystem(GenericSystem aSystem) { mySystem = aSystem; }
}

public class PhysicsComponent : Component
{
    int pos;    

    public PhysicsComponent(int x) : base() { pos = x; }
}


public abstract class GenericSystem : List<Component>
{
    public Type ComponentType;
    public GenericSystem(Type componentType)
    { ComponentType = componentType; }
    public void RegisterComponent(c)
    {
        Add(c);
        c.SetSystem(this);
    }
}

public class PhysicsSystem : GenericSystem
{
    public PhysicsSystem() : base(typeof(PhysicsComponent)) { }
}

public static GenericEngine
{
    List<GenericSystem> systems = new List<GenericSystem>();

    //... Code here that adds some GenericSystems to the systems ...

    public static void RegisterComponent(Component c)
    {
        foreach(GenericSystem aSystem in systems)
        {
            Type t = aSystem.ComponentType;
            //PROBLEM IS HERE
            t c_as_t = c as t;
            //
            if ( c_as_t != null)
                aSystem.RegisterComponent(c);
        }


    }

}
```

The error I get is "The type or namespace 't' could not be found."

I want each `GenericSystem` to have a `Component` type that it wants registered to it.  This way, anything registering a new `Component c` simply calls `GenericEngine.RegisterComponent(c)` and all systems interested in that type of component register it.

Ideally, I'd like to have the code more along the lines of:

```
     //where T must be a child of Component
    public abstract class GenericSystem<T> : List<Component> { /... }
    public class PhysicsSystem : GenericSystem<PhysicsComponent>
```

I suspect this isn't a terribly complicated question, and I'm missing something about how C# deals with types (or, more embarrassingly, generics in general) so if it's an easy question, please just point me in the direction of some reading material.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use generic constraints to solve the "where T must be a child of Component" problem.  It's really simple - `where T : Component`.  This type of registering + notifications sounds like [the Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), so you may want to check it out.  I think you'll want to do two layers of that pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Local variable declarations and "as" do not work that way. "t" is an expression that *at runtime evaluates to a reference to an object that represents a type*. The local decl, and "as" are expecting a program fragment that *at compile time names a type*.

You're trying to put a cake onto a shelf of cake recipe books; though cakes and cake recipe books are intimately related, they are not the same kind of thing.

If you want to determine if at runtime, the object c is of the type described by the t object, then you can call GetType on c and determine if the two types are either (1) equal, if you demand identity, or (2) compatible, if you merely require one to be compatible with the other.

---

> Ideally, I'd like to have the code more along the lines of:

```
 //where T must be a child of Component
public abstract class GenericSystem<T> : List<Component>
```

OK, then say that:

```
public abstract class GenericSystem<T> : List<Component> where T : Component
```

---

Looking at your design, other things seem suspicious. Is a generic system actually *a kind of list of components*, or is it a thing that, among other things, *contains* a list of components? Use derivation to express "is a kind of" relationships. Use containment to express "container" relationships. A car is not a kind of list of wheels; a car *has* a list of wheels.

Comment: +1 for "a car is not a kind of list of wheels".  This might be a common pitfall because my earliest designs always exhibited this problem.

Comment: I really wish C# had first-class types so you could do that sort of thing - have a nongeneric method that accepts a type parameter call a generic method with that parameter: `void Foo(Type t) { Bar<t>(); } void Bar<T>() { }`. That would increase the power of C# but of course would have to do some compilation or reflection at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're writing

```
if ((c as T) != null)
```

which is simpler

```
if (c is T)
```

Then, as Eric points out, these operators need types, not variables containing type metadata.  You'll need reflection, like:

```
if (t.IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType()))
```